# Univeral link not working with http scheme

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, deep-linking

Using universal link in ionic framework(v3). It is working perfectly in android, ios(https scheme) but not working with http scheme.

I seen somewhere i can sign apple-app-site-association file and upload on http website but that is for ios < 9.

I am looking for workaround for following such url :

http://hosturl

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: it is simple question. universal link not working with http and it is working perfect with https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support Universal links, you have to upload an `apple-app-site-association` file, using `https` only as described in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains?language=objc

Then you may support http links redirecting to your apps (but if you have a valid SSL certificate, why would you serve content through `http`)

Comment: hptts is not possible. how to use http ?

Comment: You just can't.

Comment: i read somewhere. it is possible if you can sign apple-app-site-association but that is below ios 9

Comment: refering: In iOS 9.3.1 and later, the file must be no larger than 128 KB (uncompressed). If your app runs in iOS 8, the file must have the MIME type application/pkcs7-mime and it must be CMS signed by a valid TLS certificate.

Comment: my question is simple how to use http not https?

Comment: Again: You can't. Read the documentation where that is explicitly explained.

Comment: do you official link that where it is mentioned you can't use http

Comment: the link in the answer is the official documentation, explaining you cannot.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: check above link {Unique = http or https}

Comment: You must serve the associated file using https. Then your links can be http

Comment: i didn't get. can you please explain more

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick response